# find the error while making the build of the next js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I want to make the build of my `next.js` file but I found an error

> > ./pages/city/[city].js 21:20   Error: React Hook "useRouter" is called
> > in function "city" that is neither a React function component nor a
> > custom React Hook function. React component names must start with an
> > uppercase letter. React Hook names must start with the word "use".
> > react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

the code of the  `[city].js` file is

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Head from 'next/head'
import Link from 'next/link'
import CityProfile from '../../components/CityProfile'
import { getAllPostByCity } from '../../helper/post'
import { formControlClasses } from '@mui/material'
const city = (props) => {

    <Head>
        <title>YourGuide &#8211; Real Essence Of Your City</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <a rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link
            href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            rel="stylesheet"
            integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
            crossOrigin="anonymous"
        />

    </Head>
    const router = useRouter()
    const { city } = router.query

    return <div>
        <CityProfile post={props.post} city={city} />
    </div>

}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

    const post = await getAllPostByCity(context.params.city);
    return {
      props: { post }, // will be passed to the page component as props
    }
  }
export default city
```

I am unable to find the mistake. kindly tell me what I did wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the file `[city].js` to `[city].jsx`.

React component names must start with an uppercase letter `City`.

Comment: the code is in the page folder. then why do we use the `city.js` to uppercase `City.js` ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the component name, not file name.

Answer (score 0):

React function component should be in Upper case

from

```
const city = (props) =>
```

to

```
const City = (props) =>
```